# Magento 1.4.1 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ce-1.4.1.1

I currently have a running Magento 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, my client wants a server upgrade so I figured out I could put his server on a 14.04 LTS machine, has anyone done it ? and is there a howto ? I've been looking around on the internet, I did not found a clue...

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Backup the Magento MySQL Database

Step 2 Transfer all Magento Files

Step 3 Adjust the Magento Configuration

Step 4 Restore the Magento Databae Step 3 Adjust the Magento Configuration

For More info, Please check this link
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_move.htm

Magento will work irrespective of server. You go ahead. 
make sure u have backup before movement.